# Should comments that only serve to self-deprecate be flagged? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, comment-flags

For example, "I'm such a X", or "I feel like such a X", where "X" is often "idiot", "moron", or some other words I don't like to see or say.

Such comments do not seem to fit directly into any of the ["*When shouldn't I comment?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) categories, but I have no memory of running into any such comments and seeing anything I considered valuable information or anything fitting into the "*When should I comment*" categories. So my intuition says that such comments are worth flagging (at least when they can be seen without having to expand hidden/collapsed comment sections).

If I see such a comment on a comment thread without having to expand hidden/collapsed comments, should I flag it? And if so, what flag reason should I use? Should I flag it as being unfriendly/unkind? It does seem like that would fit, except that the comment is unfriendly/unkind to the commenter's own self, which is a little different than what I'm *guessing* the original intent was for that flag reason (flagging unfriendly comments directed at *other* people). And would "unfriendly/unkind" make sense for "I feel like such a X" as opposed to "I'm such a X"? or would it make more sense to use "no longer needed" for "I feel like such a X"?

Comment: I'd go with *No Longer Needed*. They aren't attacking anyone else, or attempting to insult someone or be rude, so I wouldn't personally go with Unfriendly/Unkind. A mod would be able to say what is preferred better than I can, though

Answer (score 10):

Comments like this are effectively saying

> Thank you it worked

Without saying thanks.

From the Help Center page you linked, it said that you should not comment to add compliments, which is what that basically is

> Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;

<sub>[From comment everywhere privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)</sub>

---

Like [cocomac said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385514/should-comments-that-only-serve-to-self-deprecate-be-flagged-if-so-how#comment1285586_385514), you should flag as no longer needed.

You should not flag as unfriendly or unkind since it’s not being unkind to another person as you pointed out. We have all said things like this when we were learning something new, and it’s not unfriendly— if anything, it’s saying "thanks" like I said above.

Comment: huh. I definitely did not make make the connection between saying "I'm such a X" and saying "thanks". I still can't really make that mental connection/leap in my head after reading this. "I'm such a X" is definitely _not_ how _I_ say thank you to people IRL or online.

Comment: @starball Im not saying it is saying thanks but it sort of is. Think of it this way. When you are learning something new and you ask a question. You get an answer that solves it and its a lot similar than you though. You may jokingly say that you're stupid since you missed the simple solution. And by saying that you are saying that it solved the problem